# Send Map to servlet with Ajax JSON

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, hibernate, tomcat

I'm building a Tomcat project, but I need to send a JavaScript Map to the Servlet.

I tried to do this with JSON and Ajax. With a simple array I don't have any problems. But when I send a map on the server side it only prints "[Ljava.lang.String@" and the reference. But not the contents.

This is my code: My map name is ticket, and this is its structure:

```
ticket[id] = { nombre: nombre, precio:price,cantidad: 1 };
```

On the client side I call this function to send this Map via Ajax.

First I transform the map to a JSON:

```
var datos=JSON.stringify(ticket);
```

And I send the request like this:

```
$.ajax({
         url:"VentaProductos",
         type:"POST",
         dataType:'json',
         data: {datos},
         success:function(data){
         alert("OK")
            },
        });
```

And this is the server side. This is inside the method doPost():

```
String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("datos");
System.out.println("Servlet"+request.getParameterValues("datos").toString());
if(myJsonData!=null) {
    System.out.println("It works");
};
```

`System.out.println` only prints "Servlet [Ljava.lang.String;@320aaecf" only a reference.
How can I solve it to receive the contents of this Map?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally changed the Map for a multidimensional array and it works with this:

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"VentaProductos",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            // codes....
        },
        data: {json: JSON.stringify(multidimensionalarray)}
    });
```

And server side:

```
String[] data = request.getParameterValues("json");
```

I hope that it could help somebody in the future :)